# Copy Range that contains a formula & Paste To First Blank Column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy range and paste in first blank column.

```
Sub Report()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("Chart").Select
Range("D9:D17").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Report").Select
lCol = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Range("lCol:lCol+9").Paste 

End Sub
```

I get an error:

> Run-time error '1004': method range of object _global failed

on this line :

```
Range("lCol:lCol+9").Paste
```

---

This is what happened:

The data I select to copy
[image]

What pasted in cells
[image]

Comment: What error(s) and on which line(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, this should solve your problemsSub Report()

```
Sub Report()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

With Sheets("Report")
    lCol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Chart").Range("D9:D17").Copy
    .Cells(4, lCol).pastespecial xlvalues
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot, It works, but it changes the numbers that copied !!

Comment: Are you copying formulae?

Comment: Yes, you are using formulae therefore you need to use ".PasteSpecial". I am not sure you can specify the Destination with it [.Cells(4, lCol)]. Try to use "worksheet.Activate" if you still have the 1004 error. The range object requires it the way you defined it

Comment: I've amened the code above to only copy the values.

Comment: Glad to hear it, perhaps you'd be so kind as to accept the answer.